# sql query oracle : want to have customized column as "Yes" or No based on the values in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables as below :

Table A

```
ID  ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    
123 Test1   Team    CommentsA   Purpose1    
456 Test2   Team    CommentsB   Purpose2    
678 Test3   Team    CommentsC   Purpose3    
345 Test4   Team    CommentsD   Purpose4
```

Table B

```
ID  ID1 Report
12  123 rep1
13  123 rep2
2   678 rep1
4   678 rep2 
3   345 rep1
```

Out Put

```
ID  ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    CustomizedCol
123 Test1   Team    CommentsA   Purpose1    yes
456 Test2   Team    CommentsB   Purpose2    No
678 Test3   Team    CommentsC   Purpose3    Yes
345 Test4   Team    CommentsD   Purpose4    No
```

Customized Col values is yes if rep2 is present for the ID in Table1

SQL query i have tried but its returning multiple rows for same ID :

```
select a.ID,a.ColB,a.ColC,a.ColD,a.ColE,b.CustomizedCol
from TableA a,
     TableB b
where a.ID = B.ID1
where b.report like '%rep2%
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from b
                          where b.id = a.id1 and
                                b.report like '%rep2%'
                         )
              then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as flag
from a;
```

I recommend `exists` over `left join`, because it elegantly handles duplicates.  You are assured of getting one row for each row in `a`, regardless of the number of rows in `b` that might match.

Also, why are you using `like '%rep2%'` instead of just `= 'rep2'`?  The latter is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `left join` and to avoid multiple records, use `distinct` as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.*,
    CASE
        WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS CUSTOMIZEDCOL
FROM
    TABLEA A
    LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON A.ID1 = B.ID
                                AND B.REPORT LIKE '%rep2%;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: +1 for using the ANSI-compliant CASE statement instead of the nvl2 function. nvl2() works great but it took a hard-learned lesson during a DBMS conversion to appreciate using ANSI-compliant syntax wherever I could.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select a.ID,a.ColB,a.ColC,a.ColD,a.ColE,
    NVL2(B.ID, 'Yes', 'No') as CustomizedCol
from TableA a
   left outer join TableB b on a.ID1 = B.ID AND b.report like '%rep2%;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no column ID1 in table A.

May be this might help :

```
Select a.ID, a.ColB, a.ColC, a.ColD, a.ColE,
       NVL2(B.ID1, 'Yes', 'No') as CustomizedCol
From TableA a left outer join TableB b on a.ID = b.ID1
And b.report like '%rep2%;
```

Please edit your question since it says `a.ID1 = B.ID` , which is wrong in this case.

Comment: sorry, but such solutions should be punished in 2020. :) this old join syntax should no longer be used. Especially with right and left joins this is totally illegible and prone to errors

Comment: Thanks Everyone, above responses has really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Another short way to get the desired output:

```
select A.*,case when A.id in 
(select id1 from tableb where report like 'rep2%') 
then 'Yes' else 'No' end as CustomizedCol from TableA A
```